# 3 базы данных игры Lineage 2, в каждой из трех ссылок ссылка на предмет blood tornado

Tags: база-данных, php

- http://l2kc.ru/item/269
- http://l2db.ru/items/loock/269
- http://ruletka2.pp.ua/item.php?id=269&item=Blood_Tornado

Как они это сделали? Суть в том, что это 3 базы данных игры Lineage 2, в каждой из трех ссылок ссылка на предмет blood tornado. У меня тоже есть в таблице эта вещь и тот же номер 269.

И тут вопрос они выводят информацию с базы данных мускула или же может программа есть которая для каждой записи в таблице делает страничку.

[image: Imgur]

Comment: да. они скорее всего используют программу под названием php (ну как минимум последние).

Comment: Конечно в php меня интересует как они это сделали